# what's the least-painfull way to have less on Windows?

Tags: cygwin, window, less, gnuwin32, unix-utils

I want to use `less`, instead of `more`, on a Windows machine.

I know I can install [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin..com/) and use its less. But I've also noticed there's [GnuWin](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/) which offers a [less](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm), a stand-alone [less](http://adoxa.altervista.org/less/index.html), and there are other [options](https://sourceforge.net/projects/unxutils/) still.

What's the least painful/least intrusive choice for making less available?

Comment: MinGW (https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Base/less/less-436-1/) perhaps?

Comment: Seems easier to just use WSL

Comment: @Ramhound: WSL?

Comment: @Mokubai: Can you explain why MinGW rather than the other options, in an answer?

Comment: @einpolkum WSL = [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq)

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Ok, and why would that be my choice?

Comment: @einpoklum - It's a feature of Windows instead of third-party

Comment: @einpolkum Lol good question. I guess the pros would be it's official MS supported stuff and perhaps potential ease of install (it's arguably CLI cygwin without the hassle, if I am not totally mistaken). You still need to meet the system requirements, however. Someone else could probably make a better case for it.

Comment: @einpolkum For my money, [the individual GNUWin32 less package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm) is the clear winner for least painful/intrusive. It's a simple download (bin and dep zips), extract where you like, put the deps folders in the bin folder and add to your path. No frills and functionality and its basically just less.

Comment: @Ramhound: But isn't it just Windows allowing you to install a "third-party" Linux distribution?

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Make that an answer please.

Comment: @einpoklum Not really, there's probably not much difference between them all and by the time you've gotten any given one of them set up then that's the hard part done and "which one" becomes irrelevant unless you can find something specific that it doesn't do that another one might.  By the time you'd researched all the options you could probably have already installed one, solved your problem and moved on.

Answer (score 1):

> What's the least painful/least intrusive choice for making less available [on Windows]?

Arguably, the least painful/intrusive choice is the [individual GnuWin32 less package](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/less.htm). It is basically just `less` with no frills, hassles or large installs.

To install GnuWin32 `less`:

- Download and extract both the [binary](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/less-bin-zip.php) and [dependency](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/less-dep-zip.php) zip files. You may also want the [documentation](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/downlinks/less-doc-zip.php) zip, but it is not required.
- Copy the `bin` and `manifest` folders from the `dependencies` folder (*less-394-deps*) into the `binary` folder (*less-394-bin*). Agree to the overwrite.
- Take the combined `binary` folder (*less-394-bin*) and place it wherever you would like it to permanently reside. You can rename the folder if wish.

**Adding less to your Path**

Finally, to make `less` globally available from the command line, add your installation folder (e.g. `C:\path\to\less\`) to your Windows System `Path` variable. This is under:

*Control Panel\System and Security\System* → *Advanced system settings* → *Environment Variables...*

In both Windows 7 and Windows 10. The System `Path` variable is in the lower pane.

*Windows 7*:

- `Edit` the `Path` variable, adding a semi-colon to the current final entry and paste your path to `less` after that. So you should end up with something like `...C:\random\folder\;C:\path\to\less\`
- Click `OK` twice to save your settings (once to exit the `Edit` window and once again to dismiss the *Environment Variables...* dialog).

*Windows 10*:

- `Edit` the `Path` variable, clicking `New` to add a new entry. Paste your path to `less` into the new field at the bottom of the list. Don't forget the trailing slash (no semi-colons are needed, however).
- Click `OK` twice to save your settings (once to exit the `Edit` window and once again to dismiss the *Environment Variables...* dialog).